# Использование STARTUPINFO для создания нового процесса

Tags: c, winapi

**Доброго времени суток!**

Есть такой код:

```
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    RtlZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
    RtlZeroMemory(&pi,sizeof(pi));
      si.cb = sizeof(si);
      si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESIZE | STARTF_USEPOSITION;
      si.dwX = 0;
      si.dwY = 0;
      si.dwXSize = 100;
      si.dwYSize = 100;
      si.lpTitle = "Caption";

 CreateProcess(NULL,"C:\\windows\\notepad.exe",NULL,NULL,false,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
 WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

Блокнот запускается, но параметры структуры STARTUPINFO не были задействованы при создании процесса. Т.е ни позиционирование, ни установка кэпшна не произошли. Собственно в этом-то и проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Эти параметры распространяются на консольные приложения. Блокнот - оконное приложение.

Смотрите внимательно документацию по `STARTUPINFO`, в ней есть строчки "For console processes" и "For GUI processes".

Для оконных(GUI) приложений, максимум, на что можно надеяться - что авторы использовали `wShowWindow`, который передается в `WinMain`. Если не использовали, то даже на изменение `wShowWindow` реакции не будет

**note:** хотя, вот пишут:

> For `GUI` processes, `wShowWindow` specifies the default value **the first time** `ShowWindow` is called. The `nCmdShow` parameter of `ShowWindow` **is ignored**.

Хотя, не припомню такой реакции именно на "first time", но может просто не обращал внимание. Но вот координат окна это точно касается, они привязаны к реализации оконного приложения:

> For `GUI` processes, the specified position is used **the first time** the new process calls `CreateWindow` to create an overlapped window if the `xxx` parameter of `CreateWindow` is `CW_USEDEFAULT`.

Comment: Именно поэтому имя файла и передается вторым параметром, а не первым:

    Смотрите внимательно документацию по STARTUPINFO, в ней есть строчки "For console processes" и "For GUI processes"

К тому же я попросил помочь примером кода.

Comment: >Именно поэтому имя файла и передается вторым параметром, а не первым
Именно, почему, не понял?  
 --  
И какой код Вы хотели здесь увидеть? Код приложения, которое будет реагировать на параметры `STARTUPINFO`?  
 --
Для позиционирования `notepad.exe` Вам придется после запуска приложения использовать `FindWindow` и `SetWindowPos` или `MoveWindow`:

    MoveWindow( FindWindowA( "Notepad", nullptr ), 100, 100, 50, 250 );

но, возможно, придется перед этим поставить небольшую задержку: `Sleep( 500 )`.

Comment: Альтернатива задержке - мониторинг потоков созданного процесса на предмет наличия в них окон с заданным классом. Это можно делать либо таймером, либо хуком на `CreateWindow`, но это уже гораздо более сложная и неоднозначная задача. Для "бытовых" нужд сойдет и `Sleep`.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже заметил [[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega), фокусы с STARTUPINFO работают только с консольными приложениями.
В вашем же случае сценарий примерно такой (подразумеваю, что бан в гугле еще не поймали):

1. [get process window handle](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&authuser=0#hl=en&tbo=d&authuser=0&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+get+process+window+handle&oq=how+to+get+process+window+handle&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.26671.27968.2.28209.7.2.0.5.5.0.141.232.1j1.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.NekJBfCkhIE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.bGE&fp=c733366a4675afd4&biw=1588&bih=957)
2. [change window title](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+change+window+title+winapi&oq=how+to+change+window+title+winapi&gs_l=hp.3...46306.47501.3.48014.7.7.0.0.0.0.116.727.3j4.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.B4oZYrQtCPc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.bGE&fp=c733366a4675afd4&biw=1588&bih=957)
3. [set window position and size](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&authuser=0#hl=en&tbo=d&authuser=0&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+set+window+position+and+size+winapi&oq=how+to+set+window+position+and+size+winapi&gs_l=hp.3...3934.5317.1.5560.7.7.0.0.0.0.135.592.5j2.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.4RLQnuMoDec&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1588&bih=957&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&cad=b)

P.S.: Зачем в вашем коде Native API, когда то же самое есть не только в обычном WinAPI, но даже в CRT - наверное, одному б-гу известно :)

Comment: @Flammable: думаю, в использовании Native API виноваты клавиши Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V.